# gcloud appengine socketio is always disconnect

Tags: google-app-engine, socket.io, port, gcloud-node

I am working over gcloud, I use nodejs and socketIO, I am working with simple socket networking, connection, disconnect and ping.

Everything is working great over my local linux machine.

When I deploy to gcloud, it doesn't work. I got disconnection once I connect to the server from the client.

I use port 8080|| process.env.PORT

What's wrong with that.

How can I get it working over gcloud.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you're using App Engine? maybe it's Compute Engine?

Comment: So, how can i make sure of that ??

Comment: ??? check what you're using. this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/ or this https://cloud.google.com/compute/

Comment: Ok, I use app engine

Comment: How do you open sockets then? Appengine doesn't allow sockets, as well as NodeJs. Are you using a custom Managed VM?

Comment: I don't use custom managed vms, thats how my app.yaml file locks like:
runtime: nodejs
vm: true

What should I do to get them work using compute engine ?

Comment: I see. `vm: true` means Managed VM. you're using Managed VM. It should support sockets, nodejs and anything, it's basically managed compute engine

Comment: Ok, thanks for your clarifications.
Do you think I have to add something manually to get it work ?? like open a firewall port over the cloud or something like that.

Comment: If I don't use ip forwarding, will sockets work over 8080 port.

Comment: I guess you need to listen on different port, 8080 proxied to 80 by nginx by default. you need to use another port, but i'm not sure if it works, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638401/exposing-multiple-ports-from-within-a-managedvm

Comment: There's an example app for socketio on Managed VMs [here](https://github.com/jdeskins/socketio-gcmvm).

Comment: @Nick I tried it, but I found a problem with.
Could you please review it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926954/gcloud-socketio-is-not-working-on-multi-instances)
Thanks